React conditional render for logged in / logged out
I am currently creating my first full stack project, a messaging app. I have managed to create the register and login function on the backend, however struggling with the conditional rendering on the front end.
How would I update the isLoggedIn state based on if the user is logged in or not? The current set up is a test run, however if I set setIsLoggedIn(true), it still just redirects me to the login page.
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter, Routes, Route, Navigate} from 'react-router-dom';
import RegisterPage from './pages/RegisterPage'
import LoginPage from './pages/LoginPage'
import HomePage from './pages/HomePage';
import MessengerPage from './pages/MessengerPage';

function App() {
  const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    setIsLoggedIn(false);
  }, []);

  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path='login' index element = {<LoginPage />} />
        <Route path='/' element={<Navigate to ={isLoggedIn ? '/home' : '/login'} />} />
        <Route path='register' element={<RegisterPage />} />
        <Route path='home' element={isLoggedIn ? <HomePage /> : <Navigate to='/login' />} />
        <Route path='logout' element={<Navigate to ='/login' />} />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  )
}

export default App

Here is my backend server:
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const path = require('path');
const session = require('express-session');
const passport = require('passport');
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const { body, validationResult } = require("express-validator");
const User = require('./models/User');
const Conversation = require('./models/Conversation')
const Message = require('./models/Message')
const conversationRouter = express.Router();
const messageRouter = express.Router();
const cors = require('cors');

// Linking the database 

dotenv.config();
const mongoDb = process.env.MONGO_URL

const connectDatabase = async () => {
    try {
        await mongoose.connect(mongoDb);
        console.log("Connected to database")
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        process.exit(1);
    }
}

app.use(cors({
    origin: 'http://localhost:3000'
  }));
// Set up views and view engine 

app.set('views', __dirname);
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// Set up middleware
app.use(express.json());
app.use(session({secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET, resave: false, saveUninitialized: true }));
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: false}));

  // Conversations

app.post('/conversations', async (req, res) => {
    const newConversation = new Conversation({
        members: [req.body.senderId, req.body.receiverId],
    })

    try {
        const savedConversation = await newConversation.save();
        res.status(200).json(savedConversation)
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).json(err)
    }
});

app.use('/conversations', conversationRouter);


conversationRouter.get('/:userId', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const conversation = await Conversation.find({
            members: { $in:[req.params.userId]},
        });
        res.status(200).json(conversation);
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).json(err)
    } 
})

// Messages

app.post('/messages', async (req, res) => {
    const newMessage = new Message(req.body)

    try {
        const savedMessage = await newMessage.save()
        res.status(200).json(savedMessage);
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).json(err)
    }
})

app.use('/messages', messageRouter);

messageRouter.get('/:conversationId', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const messages = await Message.find({
            conversationId:req.params.conversationId,
        })
        res.status(200).json(messages);
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).json(err)
    }
})



// GET requests 

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send("")
})


// POST requests

app.post('/register', [
    body('name').trim().notEmpty().withMessage('Name is required').escape(),
    body('email').isEmail().withMessage('Invalid email').normalizeEmail(),
    body('password').isLength({min: 5}).withMessage('Password must be at least 5 characters long').escape()
], async (req, res, next) => {
    const errors = validationResult(req);

    if (!errors.isEmpty()){
        const filteredErrors = errors.array().map(error => {
            if (error.path === 'password'){
                return {...error, value: undefined};
            }
            return error;
        });

        return res.status(400).json({errors: filteredErrors});
    }

    try {
        bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 10, async (err, hashedPassword) => {
            if (err) {
                return next(err);
            }
            const user = new User({
                name: req.body.name,
                email: req.body.email,
                password: hashedPassword,
            });
            
            try {
                const result = await user.save();
                res.redirect('/');
            } catch (saveErr) {
                return next(saveErr);
            }
        });
    } catch (err){
        return next(err);
    }   
});


// Seting up the LocalStrategy of passport.js

passport.use(
    new LocalStrategy({
        usernameField: 'email',
        passwordField: 'password'
    }, async (email, password, done) => {
        try {
            const user = await User.findOne({email: email});
            if (!user){
                return done(null, false, {message: "Incorrect email"});
            };
            const passwordMatch = bcrypt.compareSync(password, user.password)
                if (!passwordMatch){
                    return done(null, false, {message: "Incorrect password"});
                }
                return done(null, user);
        } catch(err) {
            return done(err);
        }
    })
)

// Setting up sessions and seralisation

passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
    done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(async (id, done) => {
    try {
        const user = await User.findById(id);
        done(null, user);
    } catch(err){
        done(err);
    };
});


// Setting up the log in

app.post(
    '/login',
    passport.authenticate('local', {
        successRedirect: '/home',
        failureRedirect: '/fail'
    })
);

// Setting up the log out

app.get('/logout', (req, res, next) => {
    req.logout((err) => {
        if (err) {
            return next(err);
        }
        res.redirect('/');
    });
});

// Listesn for port

app.listen(5000, () => {
    console.log('app listening on port 5000')
});

connectDatabase();

Cheers!

I'd suggest checking out React Contexts here https://react.dev/reference/react/createContext for a better way of keeping track of your user's authentication state. You'll be able to alter this value from everywhere in your app. It's also a good idea to return different sets of routes depending on the login state - it makes it more maintainable.
